# How to fix content when implementing h2

Tags: html, css

i implement following code for `h2`

```css
h2 {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<h2>Free POS</h2>
```

I have a [website](https://www.salesvu.com).when i implement h2 in their content part then line become break. so have any idea how can i resolve it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide enough code to replicate your error within the question - see how to create a [MCVE] and [something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: explain more detail about your issue

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are saying is whenever you use an h2 tag, it forces a line break.  If this is the case, I have had this issue before and I use Css to solve my problem .

```
<style>
#hTwo { font-size: 22px; }
</style>


<span id="hTwo"> my h2 text </span> without a line break
```